# Why Are Percentage Gains Used for Capital Gains Tax Calculations?

Tags: united-kingdom, calculation, capital-gains-tax

In the context of UK investments, I'm led to believe that encashing a general investment account (OEIC/UT) can result in a capital gains tax liability.  My understanding is that when calculating this liability, you consider the difference in a fund's initial purchase price and its current sale price to work out the taxable gain.

Let's say I've got £5,000 invested in "Fund A" within a GIA today.  I bought this for £2 per unit in 2013 and I want to encash it now when it's worth £2.50 per unit.

My initial attempt to work out the gain is was therefore:

`£5000 ÷ £2.50 = 2000 units
2000 × £2.00 = £4000 initial value
£5000 - £4000 = £1000 gain`

However, I've been told that the above is incorrect and I should be looking at percentage gain instead:

`(£2.50 - £2.00) ÷ £2.00 = 0.25 (i.e., 25% gain in share price)
0.25 × £5000 = £1250 gain`

Now, I don't understand how the percentage-based method can possibly be the correct way to work this out.  Surely if I buy 2000 shares for £2 each and then sell them all at £2.50 then I've gained £1000 by doing this buy/sell transaction?  Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Disappointing about the down-vote.  Maybe this just isn't the place to ratify what you're told by financial advisers!

Comment: You've simply got a calculation error in your percentage gain.  That's 25% times your intiial investment, not 25% times its current value.  0.25 x £4000 = £1000 gain, same as your initial attempt.

Comment: Thanks, @davmp.  The adviser I spoke to did say explicitly multiply by current value, but it's reassuring to know that his suggestion made as much sense to everyone else as it did to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pay tax on your gain, i.e. on £1000.

0.25 x £5000 makes no sense at all, yes the asset has increased in value by 25%, but that's a 25% increase from £4000, not £5000, so it's 0.25 x £4000, which is £1000, as you calculated.

You can deduct costs too though, at least those relating solely to the gain (e.g. acquisition and disposal costs), so if it cost you £50 to buy and sell, you'd be liable for capital gains on £950 in fact.